# How to get correlation of two vectors in python

Tags: python, numpy

In matlab I use

```
a=[1,4,6]
b=[1,2,3]
corr(a,b)
```

which returns .9934. I've tried `numpy.correlate` but it returns something completely different. What is the simplest way to get the correlation of two vectors?

Comment: See @lgautier answer [here]http://stackoverflow.com/a/15026044/1982962)

Comment: Have you tried corrcoef:http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.corrcoef.html

Answer (score 194):

The docs indicate that [`numpy.correlate`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.correlate.html) is not what you are looking for:

```
numpy.correlate(a, v, mode='valid', old_behavior=False)[source]
  Cross-correlation of two 1-dimensional sequences.
  This function computes the correlation as generally defined in signal processing texts:
     z[k] = sum_n a[n] * conj(v[n+k])
  with a and v sequences being zero-padded where necessary and conj being the conjugate.
```

Instead, as the other comments suggested, you are looking for a [Pearson correlation coefficient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_product-moment_correlation_coefficient). To do this with scipy try:

```
from scipy.stats.stats import pearsonr   
a = [1,4,6]
b = [1,2,3]   
print(pearsonr(a,b))
```

This gives

```
(0.99339926779878274, 0.073186395040328034)
```

You can also use `numpy.corrcoef`:

```
import numpy
print(numpy.corrcoef(a,b))
```

This gives:

```
[[ 1.          0.99339927]
 [ 0.99339927  1.        ]]
```

Comment: what is the second value in the tuple printed by "pearsonr(a,b)"?

Comment: @MuhammadHaseebKhan According to the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.pearsonr.html) the values it returns are (Pearson’s correlation coefficient, 2-tailed p-value)

Comment: Hi @Hooked: I have 2 vectors in 2 columns. I want their corr coef in another column. How can I do that? Thanks!