# Numpy correlation confusion

Tags: python, numpy, correlation

I want to compute the correlation between 2 arrays. For this, I would like to use NumPy.

I used the `numpy.correlate` function on a small example:

```
import numpy as np

a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [2, 3, 4]

np.correlate(a, b)
>>> np.array([20])
```

I don't really know how to interpret that result. What I would like to have is a number between -1 and 1 to indicate the correlation, with 1 meaning the arrays are positively related and -1 meaning the arrays are negatively related.

How can I get this number?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're using the wrong function. You're looking for [`numpy.corrcoef`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.corrcoef.html), which actually calculates the correlation coefficient.

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [2, 3, 4]

>>> np.corrcoef(a, b)
array([[ 1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.]])
```

[As mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29612360/numpy-correlation-confusion/29612381?noredirect=1#comment47370302_29612381) by Hooked, this returns a matrix of values from the covariance matrix.

Should you want the Pearson correlation coefficient, you can use `pearsonr` from `scipy.stats.stats`. [Hooked's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19429478/4686625) is a proper implementation of this method.

Comment: It should be noted that this returns a _matrix_ of values from the covariance matrix. I think OP is looking for the pearson correlation coefficient.

Comment: How to interpret this matrix? Isn't it possible to get a single number?

Comment: @JNevens Ahh, you are looking for the Pearson. I'd follow the dupe then, Hooked has a good answer there.